# Encoding strings to send as parameters trough exec?

Tags: php, exec

I need to send short yet unpredictible strings to a script with with exec but I can't figure out what encoding to use to send them. I tried base64 but that doesn't work (guess the "=" has something to do with it). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`escapeshellarg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) or [`escapeshellcmd()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php).